# ios swift How to programmattically change background color of view on screen rotation?

Tags: swift, layout, orientation

This is part of a much bigger issue I  am having. I have simplified it for you. I want to programmatically change the background color of view on device orientation ?

The following code prints "landcape" and "portrait" in the debugging console every-tome I  rotate the device in the simulator :-

```
  import UIKit
  class OrientationViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("landscape")
    } else {
        print("portrait")
    }
  }
}
```

Though the following code does nothing :-

```
   import UIKit
   class AskitViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let landscapesmallview = UIView()
    landscapesmallview.backgroundColor = .orange
   let portraitsmallview = UIView()
    portraitsmallview.backgroundColor = .purple
    view.addSubview(landscapesmallview)
    view.addSubview(portraitsmallview)

 func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator:      UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
     if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("landscape")
    landscapesmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     portraitsmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    } else {
        print("potrait")
  portraitsmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  landscapesmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

I am using swift 4.2 and or 5, xcode 10.2
   So, how to programmatically change the background color of view every-time I rotate  the device ?

Please, any of you experts help me ?

edit 1:

I had told you'll in the beginning that it is a part of a bigger issue -

I have buttons inside a view which in potrait mode I want like this -

[image]

which is achieved by the following code -

//original potrait mode/////

```
    import UIKit
    class PotraitViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let buttonred = UIButton()
    buttonred.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let buttonblue = UIButton()
    buttonblue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let landscapesmallview = UIView()
    view.addSubview(landscapesmallview)
    landscapesmallview.addSubview(buttonred)
    landscapesmallview.addSubview(buttonblue)
    buttonred.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonblue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        buttonred.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant: 200),
        buttonred.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        buttonred.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant:-20),
        buttonred.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        //-------
        buttonblue.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonred.bottomAnchor,constant: 40),
        buttonblue.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonred.leadingAnchor),
        buttonblue.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:buttonred.trailingAnchor),
        buttonblue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonred.widthAnchor)

        ])
    }

 }
```

and in landscape mode  I want like this -

[image]

which is achieved by the following code -

// original lanscape mode/////

```
  import UIKit
  class LandscapeViewController: UIViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    let buttonred = UIButton()
    buttonred.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let buttonblue = UIButton()
    buttonblue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(buttonred)
    view.addSubview(buttonblue)
    buttonred.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonblue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        buttonred.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        buttonred.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant:40),
        buttonred.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor,constant:-20),
        buttonred.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),

        //-------
        buttonblue.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonred.centerYAnchor),
        buttonblue.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor,constant:40),
        buttonblue.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant:-20),
        buttonblue.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo:buttonred.widthAnchor)



        ])
     }

  }
```

So, I tried the following code to achieve by screen rotation i.e. two different  layouts in potrait and landscape views programmatically with the help of the following code:-

```
    import UIKit

    class NewViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let buttonredlandscape = UIButton()
    buttonredlandscape.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let buttonbluelandscape = UIButton()
    buttonbluelandscape.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let buttonredportrait = UIButton()
    buttonredportrait.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let buttonblueportrait = UIButton()
    buttonblueportrait.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let landscapesmallview = UIView()
    let portraitsmallview = UIView()
    landscapesmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    portraitsmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    landscapesmallview.frame = view.frame
    portraitsmallview.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(landscapesmallview)
    view.addSubview(portraitsmallview)


    landscapesmallview.addSubview(buttonredlandscape)
    landscapesmallview.addSubview(buttonbluelandscape)
    portraitsmallview.addSubview(buttonredportrait)
    portraitsmallview.addSubview(buttonblueportrait)
    buttonredlandscape.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonbluelandscape.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonredportrait.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonblueportrait.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([



    buttonredlandscape.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:landscapesmallview.centerYAnchor),
        buttonredlandscape.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:landscapesmallview.topAnchor,constant:40),
        buttonredlandscape.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: landscapesmallview.centerXAnchor,constant:-20),
        buttonredlandscape.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: landscapesmallview.heightAnchor,constant:50),

        buttonbluelandscape.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo:buttonredlandscape.centerYAnchor),
        buttonbluelandscape.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: landscapesmallview.centerXAnchor,constant:40),
        buttonbluelandscape.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: landscapesmallview.trailingAnchor,constant:-20),
        buttonbluelandscape.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonredlandscape.heightAnchor),


        buttonredportrait.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: portraitsmallview.topAnchor,constant: 200),
        buttonredportrait.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: portraitsmallview.centerXAnchor),
        buttonredportrait.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: portraitsmallview.trailingAnchor,constant:-20),
        buttonredportrait.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonredportrait.widthAnchor),

        buttonblueportrait.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonredportrait.bottomAnchor,constant: 40),
        buttonblueportrait.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonredportrait.leadingAnchor),
        buttonblueportrait.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:buttonredportrait.trailingAnchor),
        buttonblueportrait.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: buttonredportrait.widthAnchor)


        ])

    //-------



    func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            landscapesmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            portraitsmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            portraitsmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            landscapesmallview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

         }
      }

    }

  }
```

which in potrait mode shows -

[image]

and which in landscape mode shows -

[image]

How to achieve what I want programmatically (see after edit 1) i.e. topmost 2  buttons to rearrange themselves programmatically every-time  the user rotates the device. Its not just the buttons. It can be labels, images, collectionview etc. or just anything. The upshot is that I want to achieve two layouts  in landscape and portrait modes programmatically.

Points to be noted :-

i) I want to use "NSLayoutConstraint.activate" because apple recommends it.

ii) If possible, I do not want to use stackview or containerview,  because there can be many more types of labels, buttons etc, but if there is no other way, then I will use it.

iii) Is my code DRY principle compliant ?

Also, guys, please, I do not deserve negative marks because,  as far as I know, this has not been asked before. I request you to remove negative marks and encourage me.

Comment: What is, do you imagine, that toggling `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` has to do with what _color_ something is?

Answer (score 0):

How about you set a variable and set the color based on the value?

```
 import UIKit

  class OrientationViewController: UIViewController {

  var screenOrientation = ""

  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {

        print("landscape")
        self.screenOrientation = "landscape"

    } else {

        print("portrait")
        self.screenOrientation = "portrait"

    }
  }
```

```
if self.screenOrientation == "landscape" {
   self.yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.//set color
}
else if self.screenOrientation == "portrait" {
   self.yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.//set different color
}
else{
   self.yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.//set default color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image][image][image]
i had make to view one for `portraitsmallview` and one for `landscapesmallview`
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var landscapesmallview = UIView()
    var portraitsmallview = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    landscapesmallview.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500)
    landscapesmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow     //give color to the view
    landscapesmallview.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(landscapesmallview)

    portraitsmallview.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
    portraitsmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue     //give color to the view
    portraitsmallview.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(portraitsmallview)

    landscapesmallview.isHidden = true
    portraitsmallview.isHidden = true
        }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            landscapesmallview.isHidden = true
            portraitsmallview.isHidden = false
        } else {
            landscapesmallview.isHidden = false
            portraitsmallview.isHidden = true

        }
    }
}
```

and if you need change the backgrandcolor `landscapesmallview.backgroundColor` and `portraitsmallview.backgroundColor`

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by Younouss EL OUATI on 5/29/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Younouss EL OUATI. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var landscapesmallview = UIView()
    var portraitsmallview = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    landscapesmallview.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500)
    landscapesmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow     //give color to the view
    landscapesmallview.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(landscapesmallview)

    portraitsmallview.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
    portraitsmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue     //give color to the view
    portraitsmallview.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(portraitsmallview)

    landscapesmallview.isHidden = true
    portraitsmallview.isHidden = true
        }
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            landscapesmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            landscapesmallview.isHidden = true
            portraitsmallview.isHidden = false
        } else {
            portraitsmallview.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            landscapesmallview.isHidden = false
            portraitsmallview.isHidden = true

        }
    }
}
```